# How to remove XML elements and all children?

Tags: php, xml

I need to read an `XML` file and delete all the elements named `<images>` and all the children associated. I have found similar old questions that did not work. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better method?

`XML:`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<settings>
  <background_color>#000000</background_color>
  <show_context_menu>yes</show_context_menu>
  <image>
    <thumb_path>210x245.png</thumb_path>
    <big_image_path>620x930.png</big_image_path>
  </image>
  <image>
    <thumb_path>200x295.png</thumb_path>
    <big_image_path>643x950.png</big_image_path>
  </image>
</settings>
```

`PHP:`

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('test.xml');
$thedocument = $dom->documentElement;
$elements = $thedocument->getElementsByTagName('image');

foreach ($elements as $node) {
  $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}

$save = $dom->saveXML();
file_put_contents('test.xml', $save)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out after a good night of sleep. It was quite simple actually.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
unset($xml->image);
$xml_file = $xml->asXML();
$xmlFile = 'test.xml';
$xmlHandle = fopen($xmlFile, 'w');
fwrite($xmlHandle, $xml_file);
fclose($xmlHandle);
```

*Edit:* You probably want to make it save directly:

```
$file = 'test.xml';

$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
unset($xml->image);
$success = $xml->asXML($file);
```

See [`SimpleXMLElement::asXML()`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/SimpleXMLElement.asXML).

Comment: +1: Nice way for your particular case using SimpleXML. I thought you were looking for DOMDocument.

Comment: @hakre I was working with two solutions and the SimpleXML was simple indeed :)

Answer (score 1):

In the PHP Manual page (where you should always go 1st :-) one awesome contributor points out that:

> [You can't remove DOMNodes from a DOMNodeList as you're iterating over them in a foreach loop.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php#90292)

Then goes on to offer a potential solution. Try something like this instead:

```
  <?php
    $domNodeList = $domDocument->getElementsByTagname('p');
    $domElemsToRemove = array();
    foreach ( $domNodeList as $domElement ) {
      // ...do stuff with $domElement...
      $domElemsToRemove[] = $domElement;
    }
    foreach( $domElemsToRemove as $domElement ){
      $domElement->parentNode->removeChild($domElement);
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your XML is broken, see `<thumb>...</thumb_path>`and next line as well -> **fix it!**

Then, real simple in 3 lines of code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // $x holds your xml
$count = $xml->image->count()-1;
for ($i = $count;$i >= 0;$i--) unset($xml->image[$i]);
```

See live demo @ http://codepad.viper-7.com/HkGy5o

Comment: Oops. Thanks. I was running on fumes last night. I did eventually figured it out using `unset`. I did not have to iterate. I just called `unset($xml->image)` once and it took all the image elements and children out.

Comment: @dnelson: This **is** cool! Please share your findings by answering your own question!